# Dreamweaver svn commit failed-out of date

Tags: macos, svn, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS5 and Apache Subversion. Until today, the setup had been error-free. However, when I attempted to check in a file I had revised, I got the following error message from Dreamweaver:

```
SVN: #160024, Commit failed (details follow): File or directory ‘about.html’ is out of date; try updating
resource out of date; try updating
```

Background: I am the only user. SVN is hosted on another Mac on my home network running OS X 10.7. I set it up this way because I could never get SVN working on my MacBook Pro, which is running Mavericks. I have tried getting the current version, re-editing, then checking back in, but I have the same problem. Reverting the file and re-editing also fails on check-in.

In Terminal on the Mac running svn, I tried `svn cleanup` (& `sudo svn cleanup`), both of which produced the following response: `svn: '.' is not a working copy directory`. SVN update produces but one message: `Skipped '.'`

I have used Dreamweaver regularly for over 15 years, but I just started using svn a couple of months ago. I am a svn novice and just followed some very great and detailed instructions on the Adobe website to get it up and running and connect Dreamweaver. Other than this one file, the check-in/out process works fine. When I right-click on the problem file in Dreamweaver's file list, go to version control, and select "Show Revisions," it is up to date; that is, it shows all revisions up to the last one I was able to successfully check in.

This particular file has few revisions to date, so if it is easier and quicker to somehow kick it out of svn altogether and just save the current version back, that would be fine. However, I do need to be able to save version changes of it going forward, as I anticipate significant changes in the future.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've had these errors before.  select the file and get the latest version from the server.  The commit should work fine again.

Don't know what causes it but this has worked for me several times.